# Oracle 11g Analytic Workspace Manager, error when trying to connect to database

Tags: oracle11g

I installed Oracle 11g on my Windows 7 x64. Then i download the Analytic Workspace Manager from Oracle OTN, and I ran the .jar file and it worked good. But when I try to connect to a database in the login screen, this error appears:

> \app\Demo\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\ocijdbc11.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Does anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: make sure used java is  belongs to 64 bit version.

Comment: You are right, i have x32 version of java. I had to install the x32 version because i had a problem with SQL Developer and x64 bits version of java. I'm going to re install java to check if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things to solve this error. At the end, it was a mistake when writing the TNS Alias in the connection configuration.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2446588

The solution is that the TNS Alias must be in this format: host:port:sid. 
I'm new in Oracle, i realized that errors information helps for nothing but for confusing!!